# Lost messages over XMPP on device disconnected

Tags: android, xmpp

I'm trying to develop a turn base game over XMPP. ( The only solution I found for multiplatform game ). I can send messages without problems. If the other user isn't online, the server (OpenFire) save it for later deliver.

The problem cames when a device change the network ( change from 3g to WiFi, change 3g IP... ) or the device lost the network ( turn off 3g, wifi or lost connection ). The server thinks that the device is online and send the message but it ( obviusly ) never arrive, so packet is lost.

I know one solution. Implement ACK over my game protocol, but I don't like this idea to much. Do you have any other suggestion? I think this is a server problem. Do you know another server witch implements TCP or ACK?

Thank you!!

EDIT: I do that: Connect device to server. I turn down the 3G and WiFi connectivity to the device. Android and the server still thinking that the connection is alive.

http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-331

PD: I ask to openfeint for they multiplayer api, but they didn't asnwer me...

Comment: ohh. i have involved . may you develop this?

Comment: Hi LeiNaD_87 did you find the solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: No, I didn't. I've also stopped studying this problem.

Comment: By implementing ping server to client server was able to disconnect connection after 10 sec and put all message in queue if ping can be afforded then its a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although BOSH will likely work in this case, another option is [XEP-0198](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html): Stream Management.  This will allow you to have all of the performance of a fully-connected socket, along with quick reconnects, positive acking, and queuing while un-acked or disconnected in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Under some conditions TCP/IP is not reliable. This is why ACKs, message receipts, IQs or other extensions in XMPP can solve this problem.
I have done lots of mobile programming over the years, also often with Openfire. But I have not seen lost messages. So I assume that there is a problem in either the library you are using on Android, or the Openfire version you use.
Instead of using raw sockets you can also use BOSH:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html
BOSH is based on WebRequests like Comet and works very well in environments where you switch or loose often the connection. It can keep the connection alive until your network is back and does not result in connection drops when one or more requests fail in a row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I think BOSH isn't a good solution for this case. The mobile device can connect through another interface/IP...

Comment: I just test BOSH on OpenFire and the result was the same. Lost packets on network interface changed. I activated BOSH on OF configuration and y change smack conection to BOSHConnection.

Comment: This depends on the codebase you use and your server configuration. Your server must be configured to keep alive the session long enough and you library must support resending requests and not to disconnect on network failures.

Answer (score 0):

I too came across this issue and been trying to figure out a proper way to get this resolved.

Problem for me is that I set the offline messages policy to "Always Store" and thus XEP-0184 doesn't really help out to determine if a message is not getting delivered to its receiver.

Providing this scenario:
 - I have 2 users chatting, call them A and B
 - A sends B a message while B's connection just got lost
 - The message got dropped and A is not notified
 - In this case A does not know that the message got dropped, it'll just assume that the message is delivered to the server, server will eventually deliver it to B
 - B lose the message forever

So I temporarily put in a work around for this... i store all those messages that are not delivered (i.e. haven't receive the message delivery receipt) into a queue, then periodically (say, 6 minutes - it's the time when those dead connections got wiped) check every message of the queue to see if the intended recipient is "Online" AND the receipt's still not received... If it's the case, then I mark that message as "Failed delivery"

This is quite a terrible way to fix it (please advise if you have a better way of doing it). I think the best thing to do is to have the server to do this: if message failed to deliver and the offline message policy is "Always Store", then we store it to "ofoffline" for delayed delivery.

Comment: You might consider to remove the question part from your answer, to avoid that it could be marked as "not an answer"

Comment: Thank you. I've removed the question part

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one, but I was solving such an issue recently. It helped me when I set the XMPP resource (the last part of full JID) to something reasonable, when building connection. Otherwise it will be random generated on each reconnect - and that changes the full JID.