# Android Smack API

Tags: android, asmack

While chating if internet connection of one client goes down the other client still shows it online and messages sent at that time by connected client are lost. Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: No there is nothing you will do in that case,
but there are some alternative, you can use the plugins and manage such a way which you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost messages over XMPP on device disconnected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690020/lost-messages-over-xmpp-on-device-disconnected)